# What does "EGPCS" mean in PHP?

Tags: php

I found the following code in `php.ini`. what does that mean?

And "PHP registers" -- what is that?

```
; This directive describes the order in which PHP registers GET, POST, Cookie,
; Environment and Built-in variables (G, P, C, E & S respectively, often
; referred to as EGPCS or GPC).  Registration is done from left to right, newer
; values override older values.
variables_order = "EGPCS"
```

Comment: @Sean Bright: yes but i dont know what is the use of PHP registers?
did you see that at the bottom of my question ??

Comment: Yes.  And the answer is right there in the documentation you posted.

Comment: @Sean Bright: what is the use of these order ?? do you know that?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The manual about the directive might help you a bit more : [`variables_order`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) (quoting) :

> Sets the order of the EGPCS
>   (Environment, Get, Post, Cookie, and
>   Server) variable parsing. For example,
>   if variables_order is set to "SP" then
>   PHP will create the superglobals
>   `$_SERVER` and `$_POST`, but not create
>   `$_ENV`, `$_GET`, and `$_COOKIE`. Setting to
>   "" means no superglobals will be set.

Also note (quoting again) :

> The content and order of `$_REQUEST` is
>   also affected by this directive.

I suppose this option was more important a while ago, when register_globals was still something used, as the same page states (quoting) :

> If the deprecated `register_globals` 
>   directive is on (removed as of PHP
>   6.0.0), then variables_order also configures the order the ENV, GET,
>   POST, COOKIE and SERVER variables are
>   populated in global scope. So for
>   example if variables_order is set to
>   "EGPCS", register_globals is enabled,
>   and both `$_GET['action']` and
>   `$_POST['action']` are set, then `$action`
>   will contain the value of
>   `$_POST['action']` as P comes after G in
>   our example directive value.

I don't see what I could add ; did this help ?

Or is this something in this that causes you a problem ?

Comment: @Pascal MARTIN: am sorry. :(, why we need to set an order for these variables. i dont understand?

Comment: If you have a variable named the same way that is passed both in $_GET and $_COOKIE, when merging $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, ... into $_REQUEST, PHP has to know which one of those has to be used first... And which one of those will override the first one. This is not used much today (at least, if we don't use $_REQUEST), but when register_globals was used, it was not uncommon to depend on this order to have the right values set in our variables. ;; you can have an 'action' in $_GET and another 'action' in $_COOKIe ; but you can have only one in $_REQUEST : which one will it be ? ;-)

Comment: yea i got it!! Thanks man !! :-)
This was the answer really i want :-). 
c u on next post :)

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer above is good.  But another important point to note here is that if any of these flags is not set, that variable will be empty when the script runs, i.e. if variables_order is set to "GPCS" the $_ENV variable will always be an empty array.  Found this out the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

It controls the order in which the global variables `$_GET`, `$_POST`, etc. are defined by PHP.  The letters just stand for categories, e.g., `G` for `$_GET`.  I seriously doubt you want to mess with that setting.

Comment: Controlling the order means, giving the priorities to the colliding variable names in case register_global is set to On. For example, if $_GET['name'] and $_POST['name'] exist together, this order is important to set the value to $name.